# Create conda package across many versions

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have a very simple Pure Python package on PyPI that I'd like to make available on [binstar](http://binstar.org).  My package targets Python 2.6+ and 3.2+ with a single codebase.  I also expect that it works equally well on Windows as well as Unix.

Is there a simple way to comprehensively build my package and upload it to binstar for many Python versions?

I've tried a naive use of `conda skeleton pypi` as suggested in [this article](https://www.linkedin.com/today/post/article/20140107182855-25278008-using-pypi-packages-with-conda).  I'd like to replicate this process across many different versions.

Comment: Python versions or package versions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to build recipes for many different versions of the package, use the `--version` flag to `conda skeleton pypi`. I recommend using `package-version` as a naming convention for the recipes.

If you want to build the same package for many different Python versions, use the `--py` flag to `conda build`, like `conda build --py 3.4 recipe`. The flag can be specified multiple times, like `conda build --py 3.3 --py 3.4 recipe`, or you can use `--py all` to build against Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, and 3.4.

To convert the package to other platforms, use `conda convert` (see `conda convert -h` for usage; be sure to run `conda update conda-build`, as the API changed a little bit recently).

The easiest way to get the binstar uploading is to run `conda config --set binstar_upload yes`. This will cause `conda build` and `conda convert` to upload the packages to binstar automatically when they are done.

Comment: Any possibility of a magical `conda build-all` command (with suitable inputs specifying versions) in conda's future?

Comment: I was going to add `conda build --all` but it turned out to be nontrivial because of the way the environment variable is read and stored as global state.

Comment: Could expand on this just a bit? Where is that function defined? Is that a shell script you keep in your conda-recipes directory and then call with `$ ./conda-build-all my_python_lib`?

Comment: @PaulH this behavior is now built into conda build. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Does `conda build --py 3.3 --py 3.4 recipe` still work? I get an AttributeError when I try that, and a ValueError when I use `py all`.

Comment: @rwhitt2049 I would open an issue at https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/new about that.

Answer (score 0):

For pure Python packages that can run on any Python version, you can use the `noarch: python` syntax in the recipe.
Something like:

```yaml
requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python

build:
  noarch: python
  script: python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
```

Link to the conda-build documentation: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#architecture-independent-packages